# Using .has() with href selector

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/defencedog/2Skc7/

I am trying to remove the **online** class ONLY for administration which has a unique url namaley **/u1**. The idea is to scan all the **divs** containing TWO classes namely **post** (users reply) & **online** (users currently logged in). Then check whether this reply or **div** is from administration, then remove the **online** class thereby removing the online picture that is floating left. 
Any ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x[i]` is not a jQuery element in your example so you cannot call jQuery methods such as `.has()` and `.removeClass()` on it. So you could wrap it in a jQuery object:

```
var x = $('div.post.online');
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if ($(x[i]).has('a[href="/u1"]')) {
        $(x[i]).removeClass('online');
    }
}
```

or:

```
$('div.post.online').each(function(index, element) {
    if ($(element).has('a[href="/u1"]')) {
        $(element).removeClass('online');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thnx for making me understand, can you show me how this code can be made to work using :contains rather than .has()